# Finding Tangent to the curve that passes through origin.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, tangent-line

> Question: Find the equation of tangents at origin to the curve
> $$x^{2} (a^{2}-x^{2}) = y^{2}(a^{2}+x^{2}).$$

My work: So the equation for a tangent is $$y = m(x - x_{0}) + y_{0}$$

and to find the gradient  I rearranged the the curve in terms of $y$:

$$f(x) = \sqrt{x^{2}\frac{a^2-x^2}{a^2+x^2}}$$

On differentiating I was left with the following:
$$f'(x) = -\frac{x^5+2a^2x^3-a^4x}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}(x^2+a^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}\left | x \right |}$$

The next step that I have learned is to substitute the $x$ value (in this case $0$ as it goes through origin) to the above equation to find the gradient $m$. But that just leaves $m = 0$.

I know I am making a mistake somewhere. And there HAS to be an easier way to solve this but I am stuck here.

Comment: I have not checked your derivative, however, the gradient is zero when $f'(x)=0$ which occurs only when the quintic in the numerator vanishes. Or $x^4+2a^2 x^2-a^4=0$. Set $u=x^2$ and proceed.

Comment: You've got the limit wrong. It should be $m = 1$. Indeed at around $(0,0)$ your curve is like $x^2 = y^2$.

Comment: @ArcticChar how did you arrive at $m=1$ and curve $x^{2} = y^{2}$ ?

Comment: @SoboKevSpace is there a way of solving this without doing the derivative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solving without calculation of the derivative.

In order for a straight line to be tangent to a curve at a point $O(0,0)$ it is enough to solve the system:

$x^{2} (a^{2}-x^{2}) = y^{2}(a^{2}+x^{2})$,

$y=m x$.

Substituting $m x$ instead of $y$ in the first equation, we get a second-degree equation in $x$ and $m$.
Solving for $x$, we impose that the discriminant, which will be a function of $m$, is null, so that the point is a double point.

Namely

$\Delta=1-m^{2}=0$.

Then there are two tangent lines:

$y=x$ and $y=-x$.

The value of $x$ is:

$x=\frac{a\sqrt{1-m^{2}}}{\sqrt{1+m^{2}}}$.

Imposing $\Delta=$0 does not imply the $a$ parameter.

The condition that the point is a double point does not depend on the parameter $a$.

Comment: You mention that you got a second degree equation in $x$ and $m$. But what about $a$. How did you cancel $a$ out of the equation?

Answer (score 1):

We assume $a>0$. Your curve is
$$ y^2 = x^2 g^2(x),$$

where $g(x) = \sqrt{\frac{a^2-x^2}{a^2+x^2}}$ (we consider only $-a<x<a$, so $g$ is well-defined). Then around $(0,0)$, your curves is a union of two graphs:

$$ y = x g(x), \ \ \ y = -x g(x).$$

Differentiating and set $x=0$, one has

$$ y'(0) = g(0) = 1, \ \ \ y'(0) = -g(0) = -1.$$

Thus the two tangents are $y = x$ and $y=-x$.

Comment: Could you show how you got $y'(0) = 1 \ and  \ -1$ ?

Comment: @DBZrasengan16 It's just product rule.

Comment: Okay thank you. I better work on my derivatives.

Comment: Going through the answer again, I just want to understand that you took $ m = (+1,-1)$ and you substituted it into the equation $ y - y_{0} = m(x - x_{0})$ where $y_{0}  \ and \  x_{0}$ are equal to $0$ as it passes through origin?

Comment: @DBZrasengan16 Yes, that's what I did.